# __init__ and classmethod, are they must have the same number of argument?

Tags: python, class, oop

Here i make a class named Film, but it was error when I try to create an instance Film.addFilm("The Dark Knight", 1999, 86). I have a TypeError : Film.**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rating'

```
class Film:
    def __init__(self, title, genre, year, rating):
        self.title = title
        self.genre = genre
        self.year = year
        self.rate = rating
        
    @classmethod
    def addFilm(cls, title, year, rating):
        return cls(title, year, rating)

film1 = Film("The GodFather", "Drama", 1972, 95)
film2 = Film("Rafathar", "Comedy", 2019, 40)
film3 = Film.addFilm("The Dark Knight", 1999, 86)
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: When you call `cls(..)` , you are invoking the constructor, so you need to pass the values. But it's not a necassity of class method.

Comment: Why does that class method try to return a new instance? For that matter, why is it a class method? It seems like a _property_ would be a much better fit.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `cls(title, year, rating)`, what do you think this means? What do you expect it to do, and how? It seems like you want to create an instance of `Film`. What should be the `genre` of that instance?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have defined `Film`, it requires four arguments: title, genre, year, and rating.

But `return cls(title, year, rating)` tries to create a Film with only three arguments, which is an error.

Comment: So, what should i do?

Comment: That depends on what you think should happen when the code runs.